# Gmail Filtering Wildcard for Mailing Lists in Domain

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I'm trying to write a gmail filter which will only catch emails sent to any mailing list `@example.com`.

I tried `list:*@example.com`, but this will catch an email sent directly to me `avallee@example.com` and no mailing list in my domain. I wouldn't want emails not sent to the list

The domain is a google apps for your domain user and the lists are google groups.

Comment: I think the correct syntax would be list:(example.com)

Comment: Still picks up email from user@example.net to avallee@example.com. :(